# Umbraco Data Insert

Tags: umbraco, umbraco5

I am working on  a Umbraco CMS 5 project. I have two Questions:

1. How to add Controller for a existing View?
2. Can Data be inserted in Umbraco Database? In example If someone submit his/her information in a webpage then Data will be saved in Umbraco Database(Umbraco.sdf).

Answer (score 1):

1. 1. Create a controller in the controllers folder of your project.
   2. Create an action method in that controller with return type
      ActionResult.
   3. Do your manipulations in that action method and
      then return the view path like  `return View("~/Views/Umbraco/Your
      view name.cshtml");`
2. You can create your own custom table in the umbraco.sdf with the columns you need and can submit your information using Sql or linq(if you create an entity).